How to download secure files in non-default images?
I have a Gitlab pipeline that builds Docker containers using something similar to this template. Instead of logging in with username/password I want to use a Docker config.json file to authenticate. I uploaded the config.json to the secure files in the project. Now I'm trying to download the secure file following these procedures but since I'm using the docker:cli image, there's no curl or bash.
Here's my code:
"build-docker-$[[ inputs.image ]]":
  image: docker:cli
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: "./somepath/"
  before_script:
    - curl -s https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer | bash
    - cp $SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH/dockerconfig.json ~/docker/config.json
    - docker login $MY_REGISTRY

I get this error:
$ curl -s https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer | bash
/bin/sh: eval: line 154: curl: not found
/bin/sh: eval: line 154: bash: not found

If I use a basic job like in the example, it works:
test:
  script:
    - curl -s https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer | bash
    - ls -lah .secure_files

So what's the solution here? I can't download the files with the docker:cli image but that's the image I need to use with the files. Is there a way to download them in a previous job and access them in the build-docker- job?

It has sh. Based on alpine:3.20, looks like a busybox, which has a limited wget.

You certainly could download them in a previous job step and save the file you need as an artifact for this step. Sometimes that's the easier way to go with a busybox.

@PaulHodges I tried with sh and wget, and the command works to download the installer script but the problem is that script uses curl. So even if I wget the script it still fails.

@PaulHodges not sure if artifacts is the right solution because these are secure files. So I'd essentially be downloading a secure file then uploading it to artifacts, which is unsecure and essentially negating the point of the secure files

@jeremywat could you create your own version of the installer script that uses wget?

wget should be able to download the file. If the file is explicitly bash syntax, you may be stuck. If it's actually sh-parse-able syntax (which is possible, bash could run that) then you could just wget -qO - $installer_url | sh for much the same result. Another option is to put the entire content of the secure file in a variable, preferably masked and of "File" type, but that still leaves much to be desired for security... Do you have he option of adding layers to the image, maybe using a custom copy?

@MichaelKotzjan yeah I think that's what I'll have to do
